# Aliens claiming to be gods

Tags: aliens, religion

How would aliens go about trying to convince the current population of earth that they are gods worthy of being worshiped?  What would it take for them to become the new religion that everyone is talking about?

The why behind the joke is they are the galactic practical jokers making freshmen species appear all the more foolish. It is their form of hazing.

Comment: What era and scope are we talking? Is this an ancient era, local kind of thing or a modern era world-wide thing?

Comment: Modern, they are planning on starting tomorrow

Comment: That's a hard one, considering that most humans won't fall for another *Magic Book*, nor for any *Signs from the heavens*

Comment: I know you're asking about aliens instead of time travelers, but do any of  [this question's answers](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/15150/50) work for you?

Comment: Due to the importance of the fact, you should consider to give some details about your aliens. I mean if you talk about some with octopus heads, you got some recipe already available.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T: I think the evidence is against you there.  From Christianity through Islam to Scientology, a heck of a lot of humans HAVE fallen for one Magic Book or another, without even needing any signs from the heavens.  Now you may have problems getting them to give up their current Magic Book for the aliens new one, which gives you the possibility of interesting (in the Chinese proverb sense) conflicts between old and new believers...

Comment: Would you mind taking a crack at that last sentence again? Because what.

Comment: @Ayelis  A little better?  Apparently I didn't wait long enough before posting...

Answer (score 4):

The answer (or lack of an answer) depends on your definition of god. I can't believe that the aliens would pass as a [creator deity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creator_deity) in this cynical age. A [pantheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheon_%28religion%29) of specialist gods sounds equally unlikely.

What they could try is to pass themselves as mortal beings with "refined spiritual qualities" that border on a godlike status. Gurus, not gods.

- Start by demonstrating feats beyond science as we know it. Heal the lame, turn water into wine, raise the death. They should insist that this is a mental power, not technology, and that everybody can learn it. Or at least a select few. Of course there would be hidden technological gadgets behind these miraces.
- Then teach a few selected followers. Make sure that there is a lot of deep mediation and one-on-one training is involved. Give those followers lesser powers, but never the full suite.
- React in sorrow to this limited progress. Mankind isn't wise enough. They aliens are better, even if they would never be so crass to say it. Just look at their obvious pain as their human pupils fail to walk on water, *again*. While their teachers make it seem easy.